# Highest and lowest weight vectors in tensor products of irreps

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

For $k=1, \dots, l$, let $V_k$ be an irreducible $\frak{g}$-module, where $\frak{g}$ is a simple complex Lie algebra. Moreover, for each $k$, let $h_k \in V_k$ be a choice of highest weight vector, and $l_k \in V_k$ a choice of lowest weight vector. As is easily checked, the element 
$$
h := h_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes h_k \in V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_k,
$$
is a highest weight vector, and 
$$
l:= l_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes l_k \in V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_k.
$$
is a lowest weight vector.

Is there an easy way to see if $h$ and $l$ are contained in the same irreducible component of $V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_k$.

Comment: Shouldn't the irrep with weight $1 + \cdots + k$ occur with multiplicity one in $V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_k$, and therefore those two vectors will belong to that irrep?

Comment: I guess it has multiplicity $1$ . . . but why does that guarantee that they both belong to the same irrep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that the Weyl group acts on the set of weights, and in a finite dimensional representation Weyl-conjugate weights appear with the same multiplicity.

In particular the irreducible sub-representation containing $h_1 \otimes \dots \otimes h_k$ must also contain $l_1 \otimes \dots \otimes l_k $ as they have Weyl-conjugate weights and are the unique vectors (up to scaling) of those weights.

Comment: Sorry but I can't quite see why the the two weights are Weyl conjugate.

Comment: Let's say $h_i$ has weight $\lambda_i$. Then $l_i$ has weight $w_0(\lambda_i)$. Now, $h_1\otimes\cdots\otimes h_k$ has weight $\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_k$ while $l_1+\cdots+l_k$ has weight $$w_0(\lambda_1)+\cdots+w_0(\lambda_k)=w_0(\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_k)$$ so the weights are $W$-conjugate.

Comment: @David Thanks, that makes sense now